# Create login on website using blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, security

Im looking to make a small website with some different actions in a "company". This is based on a blockchain and at the moment you can enter an address and then do the action. I would like to do it such that you not only have to enter your address but also the secret key belonging to that address or something similar, is there a way to do that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login based on a Ethereum wallet signing a message.

See the tutorial [One-click Login with Blockchain: A MetaMask Tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial).

Comment: But using this would result in everybody on my private chain needing the metamask extension right?

Comment: You can do a eth_sign JSON-RPC with any wallet. You need to have a wallet for your blockchain in the first place.